# Solve $\text {ln x} = \text {ln 1}$ (read before you answer)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms

## BEFORE YOU ANSWER:

$\text {ln x} = \text {ln 1}$

If I ask you to solve for **x**, even myself, would simply say:

ln x = ln 1 $\to$ x = 1

But,

If I were to solve the right hand side first (since it does not contain a variable), I would get:

ln x = $0$

This would mean x = -$\infty$.

Depending on the way you solve it, it gives you two different answers. Which is the right answer? I've been doing it the first way for so long, because I don't know why I thought of the second way today, and it's really confusing to what the right answer is?

Comment: That would mean $x = 1$.

Comment: When ln(x) = 0, x = 1. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Are you just talking about the usual branch of the natural logarithm?  The one defined only for real $x>0$?  If so, the only solution to $\ln x = 0$ is $x=1$.

Comment: No, $\ln 0 = - \infty$.

Comment: The logarithm is an increasing (hence injective) function on its domain ($\mathbb{R}^+$), so $\log(x)=\log(1)$ implies $x=1$. Nothing strange, since $\log(1)=0$.

Comment: Why is $\ln 1=0$?

Comment: I'm saying however, depending on how you solve the equation you get two different results.

Comment: @learnmore: Because $e^0=1$.

Comment: ln 1 = 0, thats how it is defined. Look at graph

Comment: ln(x) = 0, says the y value is 0.

Comment: Can you explain why you think $-\infty $ is a solution?  I mean, $\ln x$ isn't even defined for $x<0$.

Comment: But $-\infty$ is not in the domain of $\ln$, so how can it be a solution?

Comment: I see my mistake. Please help me in closing this q

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio;what is $\log 1$ then?

Comment: log 1 is defined to be 0

Comment: Then if both $\log 1,\ln 1$ are the same?;then how do they differ?

Comment: @KSplitX: If the comments have helped you understand, and none of the two existing answers reflect your new understanding, then explain what it is you now understand in the "answer your own question" box. After (I think) two days you get to _accept_ your own answer, which will mark the question as resolved.

Comment: then if $x=\log y\implies y=10^x$ and $x=\ln y\implies y=e^x$;Is this @Alt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you conclude $\ln x=0\implies x=-\infty$? No, it is not true. $e^x=0$ implies $x=-\infty$, not logarythm.

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiate both sides to get $x=1$ since $e^{\ln x}=x$ and $e^0=1$

Answer (score 0):

A logaritm says: to what power (x) do I have to raise a number to get the value that I know.

For example: ln(x) = 5, means: e^5 = x

So, ln(1) = 0, because if you raise e to the power of 0 you get 1.

ln(x) = ln(1) = 0
-> x = 1, because if you raise e to the power of 0, you get 1.

When you have a form ln(x) = y (where y is a known number), it's easy to solve because you just raise e to the power of y to get x

Sorry for my bad english, my math-english is not very accurate.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is helpful to look at the graph of lnx.

[image]

If we look at this graphically, we see that lnx=0 when x=1.  I think you are considering the wrong axis.

Answer (score 0):

As a real-valued function of a real variable, the logarithmic function $\ln x$ is only defined for *positive* values of $x$.  It's true that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln x=-\infty$, which is sometimes abbreviated as $\ln(0)=-\infty$.  It looks like you are thinking of that abbreviation but getting it backwards, as $\ln(-\infty)=0$.